# Google+ login Button(not G) integration in my app

Tags: android, google-plus

I tried to to implement Google+ login my app everything works fine but i want red color google+ button & it shows white colored Google button i done it by assigning foreground image but it not as good as orignal
[image: actually what i want is that]

[image: what i get]

Comment: You can check out this tutorial where i have created customized button for G+ and play service 8.4 also.
http://www.androprogrammer.com/2015/12/integrate-google-plus-in-android-app.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I done it by simply use of setScope

`SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signInButton.setScopes(new Scope[]{Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN});`

Answer (score 1):

You can find the following inside this Google's sample code:

```
    // [START customize_button]
    // Customize sign-in button. The sign-in button can be displayed in
    // multiple sizes and color schemes. It can also be contextually
    // rendered based on the requested scopes. For example. a red button may
    // be displayed when Google+ scopes are requested, but a white button
    // may be displayed when only basic profile is requested. Try adding the
    // Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN scope to the GoogleSignInOptions to see the
    // difference.
    SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
    // [END customize_button]
```

So, you can use the following:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))                
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Because, you updated the play services to 8.4.0. You can achieve this by customize your login button.

In play-services-8.1.0 google+ button is showing red color.After that google updated that logic from 8.4.0. I suggest you to create custom button for Google+ signin.